# How do I use VC++ CL call from batch file?

Tags: visual-c++, batch-file

How do I use VC++ CL call from batch file?

```
start %comspec% /k ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86_amd64
```

This works, but I need to subsequently call "CL *.c" so I tried:

```
start %comspec% /k ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86_amd64 && cl.exe *.c
```

This doesn't do anything. What do I need to correct or read about to figure this one out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vcvarsall.bat` - just sets environment variables, so when you just execute it all settings are lost at exit. To ensure that environment variables are still there you need use `call`

So you bat can look:

```
call "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64 
cl.exe *.c
```